# Proposal to rename the [catalyst] tag to [perl-catalyst]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Currently there are the following "catalyst" related tags:

[catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalyst)
[mac-catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-catalyst)
[business-catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-catalyst)
[catalyst-optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalyst-optimizer)
[flashcatalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flashcatalyst)
[enigma-catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enigma-catalyst)
[aws-codecatalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-codecatalyst)

Since the [catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalyst) tag is supposed to be specific to a Perl Catalyst framework, it would avoid misuse if the tag was renamed to [perl-catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-catalyst).

I just edited a couple dozen posts related to [mac-catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-catalyst) that incorrectly used the [catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalyst) tag. Many of those posts only used [catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalyst) instead of [mac-catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mac-catalyst). Others used both tags.

I can only assume that many other posts that should be using one of the more specific "catalyst" tags are incorrectly using the generic sounding [catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalyst) tag.

Comment: I created [tag:python-catalyst] for the Pytorch library and retagged a few questions. No idea if that's the best name, but it can be easily be changed.